# Windows Update KB2463332 Installs, But Still Available to Update?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, sql-server

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium on 64-bit architecture.  Windows Update lists one "Important" update even though I've installed it.  It is:  KB2463332.  There is no error when I install the update, however after I install it, it still shows in the list of available updates.

I've tried running the Windows Update troubleshooter but it doesn't seem to correct this issue.  Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: If a Windows Update has trouble installing (or keeps showing up even when it seemingly installs successfully), Google for the knowledge-base number and find a link to a downloadable copy which you can manually run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up hiding this update in Windows Update manager.

Comment: If you sweep the dust under the rug, it may not be visible, but it is still there (and you know it’s there… the beating of the hideous dust).